# Given $g^a, Y$, is it hard to distinguish $e(g,g)^{ab}$ from a random value?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, provable-security, pairings

where
$g$ is a group element in bilinear group $G$

$Y = M.e(g,g)^{ab}$

$M$ is a message

Does anyone know the answer or suggest some material for reference?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that the attacker has the value $g$ as well.

If so, we can rewrite $M \cdot e(g, g)^{ab} = M \cdot e(g^a, g)^b = M \cdot h^b$ (where the attacker knows the value $h = e(g^a, g)$.

Assuming that $a$ is relatively prime to the size of the subgroup generated by $e(g, g)$, and that $M$ is a member of that subgroup,then, yes, it is indistinguishable; for any message $M'$ within that subgroup, there a $b'$ for which $Y = M' \cdot h^{b'}$

Comment: Thanks @poncho Is it hard to discrete logarithm problem?

Comment: @Alex: no, it's hard in the sense that the distribution of $M \cdot h^h$ is identical to the distribution of random $M'$ that are members of that subgroup.

Comment: Good, many thanks, is there any security assumption that support this?

Comment: @Alex: that $b$ is selected uniformly randomly, and independently of $M$ and $a$

Comment: yes @poncho,  $b$ is selected uniformly randomly, and independently of $M$ and $a$

Comment: is there any reference that I can cite to support this?

Comment: There is no reference, because there is no computationally hard problem. This is basically "I know a secret value, I give you only information unrelated to it. Now, attacker, guess my value." or more mathematically: Given $g^a$, how hard is it to guess $g^b$, where $a$ and $b$ are chosen independently - and no more information given.